# How do I count the number of occurrences of multiple character values in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe "df" that looks like this:

```
Item  |  Tech
  1       F23
  1       F32
  2       F23
  2       C27
  2       C76
  3       A21
```

and I have a vector "c" with all the Tech codes:

```
Number  |   Tech
  1          A01
  2          F23
  3          C27
  4          C76
  5          A21
  6          E17
```

How can I count the number of items that share the same Tech, for each Tech of the vector below? (also reporting the zero when needed).

```
Number  |   Tech  |  Count in Item
  1          A01          0
  2          F23          2
  3          C27          1
  4          C76          1
  5          A21          0
  6          E17          0
```

The dataframe "df" and the vector "c" are really long, so I want to have a fast way to have this last table.

Comment: welcome to SO, please share data with `dput` always

Comment: I think count for `A21` should be 1? since it is present once in `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to get that count as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Tech) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  right_join(c, by = "Tech") %>%
  mutate(Count = ifelse(is.na(Count), 0, Count))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert the `df$Tech` to `factor` with same `level` as `c$Tech` and then use `table` to count the frequency.

```
df$Tech <- factor(df$Tech, levels = c$Tech) 
c$count <- table(df$Tech[df$Tech %in% c$Tech])

c
#  Number Tech count
#1      1  A01     0
#2      2  F23     2
#3      3  C27     1
#4      4  C76     1
#5      5  A21     1
#6      6  E17     0
```